# CharBuffer to string?

Tags: kotlin, charbuffer

How to get the string "hi" from the CharBuffer? `toString()` does not seem to work.

```
val a = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
a.put('h');
a.put('i');
val b = a.toString();
```

Variable states after running the code above:

[image] [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharBuffer` is pretty low-level and really meant for I/O stuff, so it may seem illogical at first. In your example it actually returned a string containing remaining 8 bytes that you didn't set. To make it return your data you need to invoke `flip()` like this:

```
val a = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
a.put('h');
a.put('i');
a.flip()
val b = a.toString();
```

You can find more in the docs of the [Buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html)

For more typical use cases it is much easier to use `StringBuilder`:

```
val a = StringBuilder()
a.append('h')
a.append('i')
val b = a.toString()
```

Or even use a Kotlin util that wraps `StringBuilder`:

```
val b = buildString {
    append('h')
    append('i')
}
```